# Sql interrogation that should return products that were sold more than 400 times returns more than that

Tags: sql, database, aggregate

I'm creating a tutorial based on a "stores" database. This is the practical part to the tutorial. I am trying to get a list of products that have a sold items quantity (`qty`) more than 400. What's wrong with the code? It should work just fine?

```
--Show products that have a sold items quantity more than 400
 Select prod_name, qty 
 From products, sales 
 Where products.prod_id in (select prod_id from sales 
 Group by prod_id having sum(qty)>400);
```

The result I get includes products with a quantity less than 400 times. I hope the image is a good enough indicator.

[image: Results:]

Comment: The title contains: *400 times*. In the question you mention *200 times* and your query sums over quantity. Clarify what you want.

Comment: why do you need to `sum` if you want to compare the `qty` itself?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend writing the query as:

```
select p.prod_id, p.prod_name, sum(s.qty)
from products p join
     sales  s
     on p.prod_id = s.prod_id
group by p.prod_id, p.prod_name 
having sum(s.qty) > 400;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- One major issue in your query is the Cartesian product with no filtering.
- Aggregate by the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`, especially if you are learning SQL.
- You have `qty` in the `SELECT`.  It should be summed up.

Answer (score 1):

you have no aggregation and no join-criteria in the main query, but you don't even need a subquery:

```
select max(prod_name), products.prod_id, sum(qty) 
 from products 
 inner join sales on products.prod_id = sales.prod_id
 group by products.prod_id
 having sum(qty)>400;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need to use `sum` since you are trying to compare the values of `qty` for each product. You can do `having qty > 400`.

```
 select prod_name, qty from products, sales 
 where products.prod_id in (select prod_id from sales 
 group by prod_id having qty >400);
```